# Send request to all internal IP addresses on local network

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, http, ip

Is there a way to send one message to all IP addresses on a local network instead of sending the same message over and over again? Does it help if they're all similar (such as they all start with **192.168**)?

(Preferably using WCF)

Comment: No, (TCP) messages have a single destination. If you want to sent a message to multiple computers, you have to send multiple messages. Have you looked into UDP?

Comment: Send a broadcast message

Comment: @Tsukasa Thanks. Looking for sources about message brodcasting now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF has two primary communication methods, TCP and HTTP/SOAP. Both of these only go to one destination. In fact, if you look at the ethernet packet stack, there is **only ever one destination** no matter which protocol is used.

For a pure WCF solution, you could have all interested parties register with a central server, then send a message to it (so it can re-broadcast it to all clients). Without WCF, you can take advantage of UDP multi-cast, which effectively does the same thing.

Regardless, the model is the same. Interested clients register with a well-known location that a message is then sent to. A service (or the router for UDP) then re-send the message to all the open connections.

In summary, the answer to your question is **no**, there is no way to send a single packet to all IP addresses on a network (without just sending the message to all said addresses).

Comment: Thanks. Looking for sources about UDP now.

Comment: @ispiro, UdpClient is your friend: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.aspx I've posted a few answers about this as well (at lest one contained the multi-cast IP range) so there is plenty of other information out there!